# Doctrine2, Error: Class has no association named children

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine2

```
$dql = "SELECT l, c FROM FakeBundle:Location l LEFT JOIN l.children c";
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
```

Но такой запрос выдает ошибку:

**[Semantical Error] line 0, col 60 near 'c': Error: Class FakeBundle\Entity\Location has no association named children**

В [документацие](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing) такой же код, что и у меня:

```
/**
 * @var Location
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection|Location[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Location", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась! Нужно было только почистить кэш